# insert image blob type into sqlite with insert into query

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, imageview

I want to store an image choosen by user into databse in Android. I use the **INSERT INTO** *query* **but I can't store the image**!!

in my class Model I have a blob image :  `private Blob photo;`

**AddBook Class :**

```
 private byte[] Myphoto;

 private void initViews() {
     imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewCheckImage);
}

  private void addBook() {

  Myphoto = profileImage(bitmap);

 String insertSQL = "INSERT INTO books \n" +
                "(name, photoBook)\n" +
                "VALUES \n" +
                "(?, ?);";

        mDatabase.execSQL(insertSQL, new Object[]{title, Myphoto});
        Toast.makeText(this, "Book Added Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

And this is profileImage method to convert bitmap to bytes:

```
 //Convert bitmap to bytes
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1)
    private byte[] profileImage(Bitmap b){

        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, bos);
        return bos.toByteArray();

    }


 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == request_get_photo_code && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri photoUri = data.getData();
            ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
             bitmap = null;
           try {

               bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(cr.openInputStream(photoUri));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }

    }
```

I can pick image from Gallery but I can't store it, I don't know where is the problem but I think is in this line :

```
 mDatabase.execSQL(insertSQL, new Object[]{title, Myphoto});
```

is it right to put Myphoto object in execSQL ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of :-

```
 String insertSQL = "INSERT INTO books \n" +
                "(name, photoBook)\n" +
                "VALUES \n" +
                "(?, ?);";

        mDatabase.execSQL(insertSQL, new Object[]{title, Myphoto});
```

Try :-

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("name",title);
cv.put("photo",Myphoto);
mDatabase.insert("books",null,cv);
```

If you wanted to insert via SQL then you'd have to convert the byte[] to a string like x'0001020304' (5 bytes).

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can avoid using BLOB type.
just store image URI as a string in database and set it to image view like this:
 `imageView.setImageURI(photoUri);`

Answer (score 0):

If you use BLOB, the application may crash.Picture byte value can be too large.You should use uri as string in your database and retrieve by uri.And then, set your imageView.

```
imageView.setImageUri(yourUri);
```